# Канонический (start, stop) в параметрах Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли элегантный способ указать параметр, который инкапсулировал бы начало и конец среза как `slice`, но не содержал бы шага?
Сейчас я использую объявление как в модуле `bisect`, но я хотел бы что-то более лаконичное и не разделять `lo` и `hi`:

```
def find_left_lt(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду передать начало и конец одним параметром? Может, попробуете namedtuple из модуля collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформить в виде кортежа. Например:

```
def find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(0, None), key=None):
    ...


... = find_left_lt(a, x)
... = find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(42, None))
... = find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(42, 142))
```

Или опускать второе значение полностью:

```
def find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(0, ), key=None):
    ...


... = find_left_lt(a, x)
... = find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(42, ))
... = find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(42, 142))
```

Или допускать в качестве `slice` и числа и кортежи:

```
def find_left_lt(a, x, slice=0, key=None):
    ...


... = find_left_lt(a, x)
... = find_left_lt(a, x, slice=42)
... = find_left_lt(a, x, slice=(42, 142))
```